# Find Next All Select Lists After First In A Super Parent Div Of Class

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a div class `superDiv` which contains 5 child divs. Each child div has a select dropdown.

Now what I want is, when I change a dropdown, 
I want to get all next select lists existing in the div `.superDiv`.

I tried :

```
$('.superParent').find($(this).nextAll('select'))
```

but this doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
var allSelect = $('.superParent select');

$('.someSelect').change(function(){
  var nextSelects = allSelect.filter(':gt(' + allSelect.index($(this)) + ')'); 
});
```